# How to add arguments on a variable?

Tags: linux, bash

I have problems on updating the value of a variable as follows:
THE MAIN SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/bash

meniu()
{
        echo "Select operation: "
        echo -e "1 - add\n2 - bbb\n3 - ccc\n4 - ddd\n5 - eee\n"

        read input

        case $input in
            1)
            add $@
            echo "The result is: " $sum
            ;;
            2)
            scadere $@
            echo "fgh: " $diferenta
            ;;
            3)
            inmultire $@
            echo "fgh: " $produs
            ;;
            4)
            impartire $@
            echo "hfg: " $cat
            ;;
            5)
            modulo $@
            echo "fgh: " $rest
            ;;
            *)
            echo Execution finished!
            sleep 6
            return
            ;;
        esac
fi
}

meniu $@
```

THE FUNCTION SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/bash

add()
{
    n=$#
    sum=$1

    for (( i=2; i<=n; i++ ))
    do
        sum=$((sum + i))
    done
}
```

I just want to take the result returned by the add function and display it.
The scripts are working but just for some values. I noticed that the adding goes bad when I use for arguments 1 1 or number smaller than my i (it starts from 2).
I think that $((sum + i)) is the problem here. :(
Any sugesstions please?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem but look into using `select` for generating menus like this.

Comment: Is there a problem with the `meniu` function? It doesn't call the `add` function at all. `i` in the arithmetic expansion is going to be the positional argument *number* not its value.

Comment: Thank you, Etan! I will look into it!

U were right. My code was in my native language and when i made the translation into english I forgot to call for "add", i did it for "sum", its ok now.

Comment: From what I know i understood that if i put $1 this will be the equivalent for the value of the first argument and so on. If its incorrect, how could I do it then? To walk throw arguments and add their values to sum?

Comment: The problem is that you have `i=1`, `i=2`, etc. and are using the *value* of `i` (i.e. `$i`). But you don't want the value of `i` you want the value of the positional parameter whose *number* is the value in `i` (i.e. something like `${$i}` but that doesn't work. The answer by Walter A covers how to do what you want (this is also [Bash FAQ 006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)) and the answer also covers an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you used simple test input like 1 2 3 4. Your add function is not using your parameters (except the first one) for adding, but the value of the loop variable i:

```
add()
{
    n=$#
    sum=$1

    for (( i=2; i<=n; i++ ))
    do
        sum=$((sum + i))
    done
}

add 1 2 3 4
echo "All seems well: sum=${sum}"
add 4 4 4
echo "I want 12, I got: sum=${sum}"
```

What you were trying to do is dereferencing the variables:

```
add()
{
    n=$#
    sum=$1

    for (( i=2; i<=n; i++ ))
    do
        sum=$((sum + ${!i}))
    done
}

add 1 2 3 4
echo "All seems well: sum=${sum}"
add 4 4 4
echo "I want 12, I got: sum=${sum}"
```

I would choose another solution, I would use shift:

```
add()
{
    sum=0
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        sum=$((sum + $1))
        shift
    done
}

add 1 2 3 4
echo "All seems well: sum=${sum}"
add 4 4 4
echo "I want 12, I got: sum=${sum}"
```

Comment: I will try " sum=$((sum + ${!i})) " tomorrow, at me is already 00:30 :D.
The while solution I dont think its very proper because i have a couple of other functions like "minus" etc. but I will investigate the " shift " option as well.

Thank you for your time, i will return tomorrow with news! :D

Comment: Your solution works just fine, Walter, thank you!
Shift function would work too, but from my understanding if I use shift the arguments will be eliminated one by one and I plan to use them again after, so the better solution is the ${!i} one. :D