# How to catch a variable from a function and sent it as a parameter to another function?

Tags: linux, bash

I use in a function a variable that was defined in another function, from the same script, but I receive an error.

```
  testare()
{
        find "$Home" -name "$({!i})"
        rez=$?
        test -d "$rez"
        t1=$?
        test -f "$rez"
        t2=$?

        if [ "$t1" -eq 0 ]
        then
                return 0
        elif [ "$t2" -eq 0 ]
        then
                return 1
        else
                return 2
        fi
}

menu ()
{
        if [ "$#" -lt 2 ] || [ "$#" -gt 9 ]
        then
                echo "Error!"
                return
        fi

        for (( i=2; i <= "$#"; ++i ))
        do
                testare "$({!i})"
                rez=$?

                if [ "$rez" -eq 0 ]
                then
                        echo "Director with the same name exists!"
                fi

                if [ "$rez" -eq 1 ]
                then
                        echo "File with the same name already exists!"
                fi

                if [ "$rez" -eq 2 ]
                then
                        touch "$({!i})"
                fi
        done
}

menu $@
```

What my code should do: I call my script with maximum 9 parameters, the first one indicates the location where i must create files with the names of the other parameters. First i have to check if those names arent already present on my disc. The usage of FOR is mandatory.

The error shows up on the **** line, because of the i variable. I think " i " isnt available at that moment. How could I make this work? :(

I tried also with writing in another file the function and source it on menu, same result..

Comment: I think that the problem might be that you should check for "i < $#"  instead of "i <= $#".

Comment: Why use `$({!i})` when `$i` would work?

Comment: with **very** few exceptions (none in this code) all ${var} references  should be dbl-quoted UNLESS on the RHS of an assignment, i.e. `find "$Home" -name "$({!i}")` AND `if [ "$rez" -eq 0 ]` (yes, quote), BUT `input=$1` OR `rez=$?` (not necessary to quote). Given that your problem is with the find cmd, using the dbl-quoted version may eliminate a problem. Good luck.

Comment: @ClaudioCorsi: I have to reachthe final argument too, so I dont see why I shouldnt go till <=.

Red Cricket: If I use just $i it will be interpreted as the value of the i at that moment. I want the value from the argument indicated by i.
I manage to understand this also on "Stack", you can take a look here at my another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020863/how-to-add-arguments-on-a-variable?noredirect=1#comment59697968_36020863

shellter: I dont know why it is like u say. I tested with echo $var and echo "$var". Same result. How are the quotes influencing the result, please?

Comment: I have updated my code (above also), now I get the following errors:
./t5: line 31: {!i}: command not found
./t5: line 3: {!i}: command not found
find: ‘’: No such file or directory
./t5: line 46: {!i}: command not found
touch: cannot touch ‘’: No such file or directory

It seems that that i is still the problem.. :(

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was looking at the wrong part.  you should be using $1 instead of ${!i} in the testare method.  Remember that you are passing that as a parameter to the testare method in the main method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate `testare` and simply perform the script's function in one routine as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

menu() {
    if [ "$#" -lt 2 ] || [ "$#" -gt 9 ]; then
        echo "Error!"
        exit 1
    fi
    for (( i = 2; i <= "$#"; i++ )); do
        if [ -d "$1/${!i}" ]; then
            printf "Directory '%s' already exists! \n" "${!i}"
        elif [ -f "$1/${!i}" ]; then
            printf "File '%s' already exists! \n" "${!i}"
        else 
            touch "$1/${!i}"
        fi
    done
    exit 0
}

menu "$@"
```

But if you want to use the two routines as they are, then you can modify your script as follows:

```
testare() {
    test -d "$1/$2"
    t1="$?"
    test -f "$1/$2"
    t2="$?"

    if [ "$t1" -eq 0 ]; then
        return 0
    elif [ "$t2" -eq 0 ]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 2
    fi
}

menu() {
    if [ "$#" -lt 2 ] || [ "$#" -gt 9 ]; then
        echo "Error!"
        exit 1
    fi
    for (( i = 2; i <= "$#"; i++ )); do
        testare "$1" "${!i}"
        rez="$?"

        if [ "$rez" -eq 0 ]; then
            printf "Directory '%s' already exists! \n" "${!i}"
        elif [ "$rez" -eq 1 ]; then
            printf "File '%s' already exists! \n" "${!i}"
        else
            touch "$1/${!i}"
        fi
    done
    exit 0
}

menu "$@"
```

**Remember**: when you are passing any variable as an argument, that parameter to the routine is accessed by `$i` where `i` is replaced by any number `>=0` referring to the position of the argument from left to right.

For example, in your script, you had `$({!i})` within `testare`, but the variable `i` is only defined in the `menu` routine, hence using that variable in `testare` results in errors. In order access the arguments passed to `testare`, you should either directly access them, ie. `$1`, `$2` etc. or you should define a variable (in a loop, for example) and access them using that variable as `${!j}` for some variable `j`.

---

**Edit**- explanation for first comment's questions:

Consider, for example, that you had an empty folder named `dir` in your current working directory. Now you want to create files `one`, `two` and `three` in the `dir` folder. Hence, you pass it to your script as:

```
$ ./script dir one two three
```

Thus, `"$1"=dir`, `"$2"=one` etc. The line `test -d "$1/$2"` tests whether `$2` is a directory and exists within the `$1` folder, ie. whether or not `dir/one` exists and is a directory. This is necessary because all files need to be tested and created within the specified directory, which always comes as the first argument to the script (as you stated).

In your script, since `testare` is doing the testing for existence of named file/directory, `testare` will need access to the `dir` directory, hence the reason for 2 arguments being passed to `testare` in the line `testare "$1" "${!i}"`, whereby the first argument is the `dir` directory, and the second argument is the file to be tested.

As for your question on how many arguments a method should be called with, you should pass on as many arguments as needed to make the routine do what it is supposed to. For example, the routine `testare` needed to have the `dir` directory and some specified file, so that it can check whether that file exists within `dir`. Hence calling `testare dir somefile` by using `testare "$1" "${!i}"`.

On the other hand, the `%s` in `printf` is a placeholder for "string", whose value is provided at the end. For example,

```
$ printf "This is not a placeholder for %s \n" "numbers"
This is not a placeholder for numbers
$ printf "The placeholder for numbers is %s \n" "%d"
The placeholder for numbers is %d
$ printf "pi as a whole number equals %d\n" 3
pi as a whole number equals 3
```

---

**Edit 2**: If you want to search the `/home` directory recursively to check whether `somefile` exists, you can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(find /home -name "somefile")

if [[ "$file" != "" ]]; then
    echo "file exists"
else
    echo "file does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, Alexander!
I still have a couple of questions for you:
Can u please explain a bit those statements? I am not familiar with them:
test -d "$1/$2"   and   touch "$1/${!i}"

printf "Directory '%s' already exists! \n" "${!i}" - Here I dont know the '%s' thing..

And finally, the last and the most important question for me: I saw that u called my method with 2 args: testare "$1" "${!i}" How did u thought at that? Since in my function I dont have parameters in the brackets, how should I know with what parameters should I call it?

Comment: Explanation got a bit long so I added it as an edit above. Check the `Edit` section.

Comment: I need to check the existence of files and directories in the hole disk, not just in the dir where i create files. So i think that  test -d "$1/$2" isnt too good.

Comment: Why do you need to check the whole disk if you are creating files in a single specified folder? For example, is your goal to create a file with a name that does not appear anywhere in the entire filesystem, or is it creating a file that does not appear in the specified folder?

Comment: As I said in my first post: "First i have to check if those names arent already present on my disc." I think I should at least check it in Home dir. Thats why i used find command.

Comment: The purpose of searching the entire disk is still not clear to me, unless it is just a wanted condition and not a needed one. Nonetheless, you can look at my `Edit 2` in order to recursively look through `/home` directory and check whether a specific file exists. Note that I didn't use the exit status of `find` command in order to determine whether file exists, because, `find` has a success exit status `0` whether or not if finds the file being asked.

Comment: Got it, iI really didnt know the return thing on find. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this (comments and suggestions  in the script) :

```
# Explicit function name
found() {
    if [[ -f "$1" ]];then
        foundtype="file"
        # found() success, return 0
        return 0
    elif [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
        foundtype="directory"
        return 0
    else
        # found() failed, return 1
        return 1
    fi
}

menu () {
    if [ $# -lt 2 ] || [ $# -gt 9 ]
    then
        # Explicit message sent to stderr
        echo "Error : you must provide from 2 to 9 parameters" >&2
        # exit script with 1 status code (failed)
        exit 1
    fi

    destdir="$1"
    shift
    # loop over params
    for file in "$@"
    do
        if found "$destdir/$file"; then # found value = found() return code
            echo "$destdir/$file" "is an existing" "$foundtype";
            continue; # next iteration
        else
            # create destination dir if doesn't exist (as dir or as file)
            [ ! -d "$destdir" ] && [ ! -f "$destdir" ] && mkdir "$destdir"
            echo "Creating $destdir/$file" &&  touch "$destdir/$file"
        fi
    done
}
menu "$@"
```

Comment: Very elegant approach, Kenavoz, thank you!
Can u please explain a little couple of thing that i am not familiar with?
1. foundtype="file" - Were the quotes absolutely necessary here? Why?
2. echo "Error" >&2 is this impacting anyhow the displayed message? What good if it is in the stderr basket?
3. if found "$destdir/$file" - i dont understand the / thingy. :D
 echo "$destdir/$file" "is an existing" - same here
4.  [ ! -d "$destdir" ] && [ ! -f "$destdir" ]

Comment: Thanks Marko ! 1. Use double quotes to avoid shell expansion (eg. when var is used as param). You can omit them in this case, but it's a good reflex to have. 2. Why `>&2` ? eg. if script redirects standard output to file, `>&2` prevent error messages  to be included in the file. 3. `$destdir/$file` concatenates dir + `/` + file (=the file location). 4. checks that first param (the dir) does not exist before creating it.